# Find an element in an HList

Tags: haskell, hlist

I'm trying to write two functions to extract a value from an `HList`, but I can't seem to make GHC happy.

The first function would have signature `extract :: HList a -> [b]` which extracts all the elements of type `b` from the list. I only succeeded in writing it by asking the types in `a` to have `Typeable` instances.

```
class OfType a b where
    oftype :: a -> [Maybe b]

instance OfType (HList '[]) b where
    oftype = const []

instance (Typeable t, Typeable b, OfType (HList ts) b) => OfType (HList (t ': ts)) b where
    oftype (x :- xs) = (cast x :: Maybe b) : oftype xs

extract :: OfType a b => a -> [b]
extract = catMaybes . oftype
```

Which is suboptimal, as one doesn't really need the `Typeable` constraint to write any instance of extract.

I tried to use type equalities and inequalities in constraints, but this only gave me overlapping instances.

The second function I'm trying to write would have signature `extract' :: Contains h n => HList h -> n` which extracts the first element of type `n` in the list, and the context says that the list actually contains one element of that type.

Is it possible to write `extract` without `Typeable` constraints?

Is it possible to write `extract'` without `Typeable` constraints?
How can one write `Contains`?

Comment: What you want are `hOccurs` and `hOccursMany` in `Data.HList.Occurs`. They don't support things like `Num a => HList '[Char, a, Char]` well though.

Comment: I can't seem to make `hOccurs` work, I'm tring with `hOccursFst (HCons 'a'  HNil) :: Char`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't checked that carefully enough. It's `hOccursFst` but not `hOccurs` that fulfills your requirement. Sorry again.

Comment: I meant that `hOccursFst` is not working for me, sorry

Comment: Can you please append your exact use case to your question? `hOccursFst (HCons 'a' HNil) :: Char` works for me in ghci. No language extensions and the only thing I imported is `Data.HList`.

Comment: I was probably mistyping something, works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to check for type equality at compile time, I believe overlapping instances are unavoidable (and I'm not a fan of those...).

Also, I'm not 100% sure I got the overlapping pragmas right.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables,
    MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
module HListFilter where

import Data.HList.HList

class OfType a b where
    oftype :: a -> [b]

instance OfType (HList '[]) b where
    oftype = const []

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (OfType (HList ts) t) => OfType (HList (t ': ts)) t where
    oftype (HCons x xs) = x : oftype xs

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (OfType (HList ts) b) => OfType (HList (t ': ts)) b where
    oftype (HCons _ xs) = oftype xs

test :: HList '[Int, Char, [Char], Char, Bool]
test = HCons (1::Int) (HCons 'a' (HCons "foo" (HCons 'b' (HCons True HNil))))

test_result :: [Char]
test_result = oftype test  -- "ab"
```

Comment: Overlapping instances are avoidable. We can compute a `[Bool]` lifted list from `[*]` with a closed type family that indicates the positions of the target type, then implement `extract` with a non-overlapping class based on that.

Comment: @AndrásKovács can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @AndrásKovács That would indeed be cleaner. I somehow think of type families defined through overlapping equations to live in the same realm of overlapping instances -- I don't know if they can raise similar issues.

Comment: AFAIK closed type families remove all the evil of overlapping instances. GHC won't reduce a type family by an equation unless it can prove none of the earlier equations can be matched. The dubious advantage of overlapping instances is that you can define an overlapping instance in a different module than the instance it overlaps, which is also where the coherence problems come in. That's not possible with closed type families since they are defined in a single declaration.

Comment: @chi, I don't think they raise the same *coherence* issues, but I think they may raise some similar flexibility issues. You may have to deal with explicit evidence of equality, or, worse, the right sort of inequality, to deal with dynamic matters. I'm not really sure how bad it gets, but I'm pretty suspicious of them myself.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, I think my answer has finally evolved into something reasonable. Is that what you were thinking? Are there any improvements you would suggest?

Answer (score 3):

András Kovács referred to a type family approach. This is one way to do it:

```
type family Equal (x :: *) (y :: *) where
  Equal x x = 'True
  Equal x y = 'False

type family Check (b :: *) (as :: [*]) :: [Bool] where
  Check b '[] = '[]
  Check b (a ': as) = (b `Equal` a) ': Check b as

class ps ~ Check b as =>
    OfType (ps :: [Bool]) (as :: [*]) b where
  extract :: HList as -> [b]
```

The `ps ~ Check b as` superclass context is critical here, as a matter of timing. GHC always commits to an instance *before* checking the instance constraints, but it doesn't even try to find an instance until *after* solving the superclass constraints. So we need to use the superclass constraint to fix which instances to select.

```
instance OfType '[] '[] b where
  extract HNil = []

instance (OfType ps as b, a ~ b) =>
           OfType ('True ': ps) (a ': as) b where
  extract (HCons x xs) = x : extract xs

instance (OfType ps as b, Equal b a ~ 'False) =>
    OfType ('False ': ps) (a ': as) b where
  extract (HCons _ xs) = extract xs
```

Once you've done this, you can actually write an interface that avoids the "extra" class parameter:

```
class OfType' (as :: [*]) (b :: *) where
  extract' :: HList as -> [b]

instance OfType ps as b => OfType' as b where
  extract' = extract
```

---

It's quite easy to write `Contains` and `extract'`. However, writing good *instances* of `Contains` necessitates exactly the same sort of hoop jumping as `OfType`. The class you'd like to have is this:

```
class Contains xs y where
  contains :: y `Elem` xs

-- Elem is part of the dependently typed folklore.
data Elem y xs where
  Here :: Elem y (y ': xs)
  There :: Elem y xs -> Elem y (x ': xs)
```

But writing instances will again force you into overlapping or closed type families. I know I've written this code somewhere around SO, but you should probably be able to work out the overlapping version pretty easily; the type family version will follow the same pattern as `OfType`, generally.

Comment: Not much to add here. There's a minor stylistic difference to how other have done this, for example [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/compdata-0.10/docs/src/Data-Comp-Ops.html#%3A%3C%3A) or [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-classes-0.3.1.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Classes-Core.html#liftN), that is, they use a class with a `Proxy`-ed method and (possibly) an additional `Proxy`-less top-level function. Looks like [this](http://lpaste.net/152217) in the current case.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, does that technique of holding off on the big equality constraint till escaping the class make type checking faster?